# How to bind Assisted Injected class to interface?

Tags: binding, guice

Here is the problem I met:

```
Class SimpleCommand implements Executable{
private final ConfigManager config;
private String name;

@Inject    
public SimpleCommand(ConfigManager config, @Assisted String name){
  this.config = config;
  this.name = name;
  }
}

Class MyModule extends AbstractModule{
@Override
protected void configure() {
     bind(CommandFactory.class).toProvider(FactoryProvider.newFactory(CommandFactory.class, SimpleCommand.class));
     bind(Executable.class).to(SimpleCommand.class);
     }
}
```

When I try to get instance of SimpleCommand using:

```
Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).getInstance(CommandFactory.class).create("sample command");
```

I got this error:

```
1) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
    for parameter 2 at model.Command.<init>(SimpleCommand.java:58)
  at module.MyModule.configure(MyModule.java:34)
```

So my problem is how can I bind SimpleCommand to Executable when SimpleCommand has Assisted Injected parameter?

Here is the CommandFactory and its implementation:

```
public interface CommandFactory{
  public Command create(String name);
}


public class GuiceCommandFactory implements CommandFactory{
  private Provider<ConfigManager> configManager ;

  @Inject
  public GuiceCommandFactory(Provider<ConfigManager> configManager){
    this.configManager = configManager;
  }

  public Command create(String cmd){
    return new Command(configManager.get(), cmd);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is Command? Shouldn't the factory return Executable or SimpleCommand?

Comment: Also, why do you have an implementation of CommandFactory? The idea is that Assisted Inject creates the implementation for you.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems.

One is with `bind(Executable.class).to(SimpleCommand.class)`. Binding `Executable` to `SimpleCommand` implies that a `SimpleCommand` can be injected directly to classes with a dependency on `Executable`. But since Guice cannot create an instance of `SimpleCommand` itself (it needs the assisted parameter provided to the factory), the bind is invalid. The error message is treating `@Assisted` as a normal binding annotation, and trying to resolve a `String` bound to it in the constructor, but none is bound.

Beyond that, it seems like if you're using Assisted Inject to create a factory for `Executable`s, you can't create another binding to it *without using some binding annotation on it*. Since you're using assisted inject, presumably you want to create multiple instances of `Executable` using your factory, so any individual `Executable` you wanted to bind directly would probably have some specific meaning in your system, right?

In that case, you should just use some binding annotation like `@Default` and a provider method like so:

```
@Provides
@Default
protected Executable provideDefaultExecutable(ConfigManager configManager) {
   return new SimpleCommand(configManager, "My default command");
}
```